# C++, header files and using namespace std

Tags: c++

So I understand that one must not use

```
using namespace std;
```

in header files. Well for my assignment we have to overload the `>>` operator. I got my program to run and all, but I had to include the

```
using namespace std;
```

Is it okay to do it this way? I attempted to overload the operator without including that command in the header file, but I got an error.

Comment: From [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/106953/22048) and [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)

Comment: You never have to pull in the entire `namespace std` at global scope and as you already know, you shouldn't. Surely there is a solution for your assignment that makes do without `using namespace std;`. If the linked answers don't help you solve the problem, you may consider asking a question on Stack Overvlow that *includes your actual code* and ask how to re-arrange it such that it works without `using namespace std;`. I bet all you'll have to do is replace `ostream` with `std::ostream` and so forth.

Comment: Why didn't you just explicitly write `std::ostream`, etc.?  This is always an alternative to `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @Lorehead reviewing the code, given that it is working and bug free, would likely be a better fit for CodeReview over SO.

Comment: @MichaelT The question asked, reasonably, whether it’s ever acceptable to put `using namespace std;` in a header file.  The answer to that is no, and I additionally said what to do instead to avoid having to.

Comment: @Lorehead and that is all correct.  It was a commentary on... ack, wrong reply. Sorry. Meant to tangentially ping 5gon - though the primary recipient is Anthony: to take the existing, working code and post it to Code Review to have them look at it more on "what can be improved".

Comment: @MichaelT “How can I modify this code so that the `using namespace std;` can be omitted?” would be a good fit for Stack Overflow, I think, unless you want a full review of it. But in any case, we have to see *the code*.

Comment: I appreciate the comments! The solution for using std::ostream worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

well ... not really. What are the parameter of the `<<` operator you are going to overload?

If you are just providing your class a way to be written on a stream, you have to chances:

1. inside of your namespace, declare a `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const yourclass& intance)` or...
2. inside the `std` namespace declare `ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const yournamespace::yourclass& instance)` whatever is more convenient for the inside of your function body.

There is no need to have `<<` as global, since [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) will find it anyway, when it is placed between object whose types match.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does resolution by name, not by signature. That means that if two functions/variables/member variables in the same scope have the same name, they can conflict. When you do something like `using namespace std;`, you are including the *entire* `std` namespace in your code.

What would happen if you had a templated function called `count` in your code that took 3 parameters like `std::count` does? You would get a conflict because (after name mangling) both functions would have the same name in the same scope. It is better to just include the parts of the `std` namespace that you want to use, so you don't introduce potential errors into your code when you go back to update it.

So, just including statements like `using std::cout;` or `using std::ostream;` will only include those functions/types/typedefs/&c. in your code.

Comment: Not by signature?

Comment: @Basilevs Not entirely. It first looks up by name to determine if it can resolve the function, then by signature. Though if you are dealing with classes and inheritance, this can get messy because it will do name resolution only, even if the corresponding method with the proper signature would be inherited from a super class (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)).